# Multiple conditional expressions depending on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a simple dropdown on my page that allows the user to toggle between viewing Actual or Planned dates/times in a table (I am using the controller as syntax):

```
<select ng-model="trip.viewType">
    <option value="actual">Actual</option>
    <option value="planned">Planned</option>
</select>
```

At the moment, my table is hardcoded to the actual dates/times like follows:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Timing</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Depart:</td>
            <td>{{ trip.departTimeActual }}</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- etc (up to ~80 conditional timings could be here!) -->
        <tr>
            <td>Arrive:</td>
            <td>{{ trip.arriveTimeActual }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to be able to switch to planned times (e.g. `{{ trip.departTimePlanned }}`) should the user change the dropdown to Planned. I have done some research into this and have found a few possible solutions but none of them seem like the "Angular way" of approaching this issue as it means adding logic into the view template:

- Combination of `ng-show`/`ng-hide`
- `ng-switch`
- Ternary expression e.g. `{{ condition ? ifTrue : ifFalse }}`

Is there a better way of approaching this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a general object for your table bindings.

Then , when type is changed you can change the object to point for current type data.

View :

```
    <tr>
        <td>Depart:</td>
        <td>{{ trip.viewTypeData.departTime }}</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- etc (up to ~80 conditional timings could be here!) -->
    <tr>
        <td>Arrive:</td>
        <td>{{ trip.viewTypeData.arriveTime }}</td>
    </tr>
```

Controller :

```
function TripController() {

  this.typesData = {
    "actual" : { departTime : 'd-t-a' , arriveTime : 'a-t-a' },
    "planned" : { departTime : 'd-t-p' , arriveTime : 'a-t-p' }
  }
  this.viewTypeData = {};

  this.viewType = "actual";

  this.typeChanged = typeChanged;
  this.typeChanged();

  function typeChanged(){
    this.viewTypeData = this.typesData[this.viewType];
  }
}
```

[See deom on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/1347/)

Comment: It means manipulating my `$http` response object which contains all of the planned/actual times, but I am happy to do this to get logic into the controller rather than the view. Thank you!

Comment: Well - it will be better to use another service for that and then change typeChanged() function to this - myService.getTimes(this.viewType).then(function(data){this.viewTypeData = data}) ;

Comment: I am already using a service to grab the `$http` response, I will adjust the response sent back to my controller to take your answer into account.